# Round to the nearest multiple of 0.75 in C#

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics

How can I round a number to the nearest multiple of 0.75 in C# / Unity?

The context is that I have a block and I want its position to be rounded at the nearest 0.75 multiple. For example: 0, 0.75, 1.5, 2.25, 3, 3.25, 4.5, 5.25, 6, ...
How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The recipe is simple:

1. Divide by your desired interval, so now each multiple of the interval maps to an integer.
2. Round to the nearest integer.
3. Multiply by your interval to bring it back to the original scale.

Here's an example:

```
static float RoundTo(float value, float multipleOf) {
    return Mathf.Round(value/multipleOf) * multipleOf;
}
```