# How to round to a multiple of 0.25?

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics

I have a problem when I any rational number so that it's 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, etc.

```
public float Coins, Money, Total;

void Start()
{

    Total = Coins / Money;
    // 3 / 7 = 0.4285714
    // In this case I need to get [1.5 or 0.5]. How to do that?
}
```

Comment: [Does this answer your question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/174619/39518)?

Comment: This is close to what I need. Here I have to set the Rational Number. What I need is to read the value, if is close of 0.25 , 0.5 or 0.75. In my case [ 3/7 = 0.428 ] this should be [0.5]. If I reverse the divide [ 7/3=2.333] Here I should get [2.25]. Because [0.333] is closet to [0.25].

Comment: How does this differ from calling the `RoundTo` function in that answer with values `RoundTo(3f/7f, 0.25f)` or `RoundTo(7f/3f, 0.25f)` ?

Comment: Does that solution you added in your question works? If so, then please write it as an answer

Comment: @DMGregory, Thank you for your help. I was missing ...... my mistake. I added the solution up and I will post it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I implemented in my code:

```
public float Coins, Money, Total;

void Start()
{

Total = Coins / Money;
Total = QuarterValue(Total);

}
float QuarterValue(float value)
{
    return 0.25f * Mathf.Round(value / 0.25f);
}
```

Comment: It it worked, don't forget to accept your answer to show that the problem is solved!